# Circle in map (size scalable)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I make map using Leaflet with one circle.
index code:

```
<div id="mapid" style="height: 500px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([52.233333, 19.016667], 6);

                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
                            minZoom: 6,
                }).addTo(mymap);

                var x = 52.233333;
                var y = 19.016667;

                    showCircle(x,y);
        </script>
```

ShowCircle :

```
function showCircle(x,y)
{
    var circle = L.circle([x,y], 1900, {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap);
}
```

The problem is : the circle always have the same size.
I want to get: if i zoomout map the circle is bigger, when i zoomin the circle is smaller. (zoomin, zoomout is from scroll)

How to get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of circles in Leaflet: `L.Circle` and `L.CircleMarker`. [`L.Circle` has a radius specified in **meters**](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#circle-radius), and [`L.CircleMarker` has a radius specified in **pixels**](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#circlemarker-radius).

Your question is not fully clear (what do you mean by "always have the same size"? Meters or pixels?); but I guess that you want to use `L.CircleMarker` instead of `L.Circle`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following , and tweak it as per your requirement :

```
  var radiusQuantifier=100;
  map.on('zoomend',function (e) { 
        circle.setRadius(map.getZoom()*radiusQuantifier); 
    });
```

This will change the radius of the circle on `zoomend` event.You can combine it with `zoomstart` event to get the desired result.
Note : Increase/Decrease the value of `radiusQuantifier` as it seems fit.